# scenario to update or insert big amount of data

Tags: postgresql, update, upsert, performance, postgresql-performance

I try to find the best scenario to update or insert 1 million contacts in my postgres database.

My actual scenario is:

- read contacts 1000 per 1000 and try to insert multiple rows with one request
- if my request fails, I go line per line to insert or update my 1000 contacts

It takes 7 minutes for 50K lines.

What is the best scenario to perform my update or insert?

Comment: This question is very similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/758945/1595345).

Comment: I used this question for my insert, my problem is when I have to update line per line

Comment: [This related answer on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12502669/how-to-tell-if-record-has-changed-in-postgres/12503305#12503305) should be of help.

Comment: Is your problem ease of processing for correctness? Or performance?

Comment: My problem was a performance problem, for now I looking for a good upsert method. Right now, I'm making an update and an insert for 1000 lines per lines. My CPU for my postgres method is around 75% CPU.

Answer (score -1):

I would do it like this:

Load all data into an empty staging table and use SQL to identify and correct problematic records before moving the data into your database.

Comment: This assumes the OP's problem is how to process for correctness. If the OP's problem is performance then this doesn't help at all.